# PHP how to convert an single array to multidimentional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have that single array and I need to convert in a multidimensional array without using `array_merge`, `array_replace_recurcive` etc, just an autonomous function:

```
$single = [
    0 => 'one',
    1 => 'two',
    2 => 'tree',
    3 => 'four',
    4 => 'five'
];
```

And convert to look like this, with the last key as value:

```
$multidimentional = [
    'one' => [
        'two' => [
            'tree' => [
                'four' => 'five'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I have create a recursion function if this helps:

```
function array_replace_recursive($defaults, $replaces) {

    if(is_null($replaces)) {
        $replaces = [];
    }

    if(!is_array($defaults) || !is_array($replaces)) {
        return $replaces;
    }

    foreach($defaults as $key => $value) {
        if(!array_key_exists($key, $replaces) || is_null($replaces[$key])) {
            $replaces[$key] = $value;
        } else {
            if(is_array($replaces[$key]) && is_array($value)) {
                $replaces[$key] = array_replace_recursive($replaces[$key], $value);
            }
        }
    }

    return $replaces; 
}
```

Comment: you've to use **recursive function**. did you try something?

Comment: No i don't use some function

Comment: I add than recursion function if i help you, but it is not do the job. This is only for replaceing

Comment: you set **$key** as array key but you told us that you want to set **$value**.

Comment: What functions can you use? you mentioned `count`, can you use `array_shift`?

Comment: Only the isset function!

Comment: If it is 100% autonomous is better

Comment: No if you use **array_shift** this is not autonomous! Autonomous meaning i create something without using other helpers

Comment: I've posted an edit to my answer which only uses `isset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking in recursion, you can write a base case that returns the value of the currently seen item if it is one less than the length of the array.

```
$singleDim = [
    0 => 'one',
    1 => 'two',
    2 => 'tree',
    3 => 'four',
    4 => 'five'
];

function toMultiDimArray($arr, $seen=0) {
    if ([] === $arr) {
        return [];
    }

    if(count($arr) - 1 === $seen) {
        return $arr[$seen];
    }

    return [
       $arr[$seen] => toMultiDimArray($arr, $seen+1)
    ];
}

$multiDim = toMultiDimArray($singleDim);

var_dump($multiDim);

array(1) {
  ["one"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["two"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["tree"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["four"]=>
        string(4) "five"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not autonomous function it is using "array_slice" function! The "count" function is ok but not the "array_slice"

Comment: Lemme fix that.

Comment: This is not autonomous, you are using the **for** statement.

Comment: Do not using reference at all!

Comment: So using __return__ also counts? And by references you mean *if* and *return*?

Comment: Very nice answer i accept it! But if you can make it and without **count** function you are **HUGE**

Comment: It's quite possible to do without *count* but one would need to know the number of items in the array ahead of time

Comment: You make a call to __isset__ in your answer. I assume the OP doesn't want to use any functions by the side. I can replace the second base case with `if($arr[$seen+1] === NULL)` but then you guess offset warnings because the index doesn't exist. I know that this can be remedied with isset but OP clearly doesn't want it that way.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with PHP (as of 5.6) [argument unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) and a very simple recursive function:

```
$single = [
    0 => 'one',
    1 => 'two',
    2 => 'tree',
    3 => 'four',
    4 => 'five'
];

function convert($key, ...$values) {
    if (count($values) == 1)
        return array($key => $values[0]);
    else
        return array($key => convert(...$values));
}

print_r(convert(...$single));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [one] => Array
        (
            [two] => Array
                (
                    [tree] => Array
                        (
                            [four] => five
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

You can also do it without using `count` (only `isset`):

```
function convert2($key, ...$values) {
    if (!isset($values[1]))
        return array($key => $values[0]);
    else
        return array($key => convert(...$values));
}

print_r(convert2(...$single));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [one] => Array
        (
            [two] => Array
                (
                    [tree] => Array
                        (
                            [four] => five
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: This is not autonomous **...$values**

Comment: In what way does having a function parameter make it not autonomous?

Answer (score 1):

```
$single = [
    0 => 'one',
    1 => 'two',
    2 => 'tree',
    3 => 'four',
    4 => 'five'
];

function to_multidimentional($array, $count = 0, $seen = 0) {

    if($count - 1 === $seen) {
        return $array[$seen];
    }

    return [
       $array[$seen] => to_multidimentional($array, $count, $seen + 1)
    ];
}

$single = to_multidimentional($single, count($single));

print_r($single);

exit;
```

Comment: That's cheating as it relies on knowing the length of the array is 5. You should use `count` to get the length of the array.

Comment: No i know the count before i call the function!

Comment: But what if you had to process a different array? You would need to change the code. My answer and @OluwafemiSule don't rely on knowing the length of the array.

Comment: This is nice question! I use different arrays outside of this function like **$single = to_multidimentional($single, count($array));** I update my answer

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing recursive about this. It's just iterating over the `$single` array backwards and then embedding the result inside the new key each time:

```
function foo( $single ) {
    $multidimensional = [ $single[ count($single) - 1 ] ];

    for( $i = count($single) - 2; $i >= 0; $i--  ) {
      $multidimensional = [ $single[$i] => $multidimensional ];
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not solve his problem. Each iteration you erase **$multidimensional**.

Comment: Nice answer but it's not autonomous you are using the for statement i need something 100% autonomous and with function

Comment: it will give E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: multidimensional

Comment: @JohnStamoutsos but he gave you part of the solution, you've to iterate the array backwards.

Comment: @AlexandrePainchaud Painchaud This is a nice answer but you can make it inside the function and without the for statement?

Comment: What do you mean "without the for statement"? That's how it works. If you take away the code, you no longer have a working solution. @AlexandrePainchaud This clearly does solve the problem: the output of this function is verbatim the output requested in the original post.

Comment: @VoteyDisciple he wants to have a multidimensionnal array with **X depth** `X = count($single) -1` your solution does not provide this at all.
Else i clearly did not understand his need.

Comment: @JohnStamoutsos you can do it by multiple ways, **for** loop his a good way to do it.

Comment: I know i already have it but is not autonomous with the **for** loop